# Where in Jira do I indicate that I have burnt down some story points?

Tags: jira, scrum, jira-agile

I am using Greenhopper in Jira and I have a user story of 25 points which has a number of tasks.

I see there is a 'statistic burn up chart', so my question is if after 3 days of the sprint I have burnt 5 story points where do I indicate this in Jira? Is this done on allocating story points to task and then closing the task?

Answer (score 1):

You don't. A story is either complete or it is not. The Greenhopper 'report' Burndown chart on the Agile board only shows burn-down at the end of each story. A story doesn't 'burn' as you work on it, the sprint 'burns' as you complete stories.

25 points? You must have some pretty high-precision estimating going on.

Comment: This is our first agile project :). I am referring to the burn up chart, why is the charts x-axis in days till the end of the sprint?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of different, yet still correct ways to manage stories in JIRA. It is generally accepted that a Story isn't complete until all its subtasks are done, it can still be useful to track progress of the subtasks. So here's how I do that today:

We divide all of our Stories in subtasks (technical/implementation tasks), and apply hour (time tracking) estimates to each of those. We estimate story points way in advance, then do more detailed estimating of subtasks and hours before starting each spring. During a sprint we use the hour/timetracking field as our more detailed tactical tracking field that stays day-to-day current.

Greenhopper then lets you view charts based on hours or points. So we use the point-based charts when looking at the overall project, but the hour estimate field for tracking our tactical progress in a sprint.

Hope that helps.